# How to find the average time between two datetimes.datetime?

Tags: python

I have two times (hours minutes in datetime format, 1 hour 30 minutes and 2 hours 50 minutes respectively)

```
min_time = datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 1, 30)
max_time = datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 2, 5)
```

I need to get the middle time between this interval 1:30 < {2:10} < 2:50

How can this be implemented in code with the datetime module?: **max_time - min_time / 2 + min_time = 2:10**?

Comment: Subtracting two datetime objects produces a timedelta.  You can do arithmetic on the timedelta and add it back to a datetime.

Comment: Aside from operator precedence issues (you need to add some parentheses so the operations occur in the right order), your suggestion works as written. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula worked pretty well for me. If you're not interested in the `year` you can ignore it or format it out when displaying.

```py
import datetime

min_time = datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 1, 30)
max_time = datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 2, 50)
mid_time = ((max_time - min_time) / 2) + min_time

print(
    mid_time,                   # 1900-01-01 02:10:00
    mid_time.strftime('%H:%M'), # 02:10
    sep='\n'
)
```

Comment: some reason, my counts are not correct `(max_time-min_time)/2 = datetime.timedelta(seconds=1020) + min_time = datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 1, 48)`

Comment: What are the `max_time` and `min_time` you used here?

Comment: `max_time = datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 2, 5) min_time = datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 1, 31)`

Comment: Seems right to me, is `1:48` not halfway between `1:31` and `2:05`?

Comment: oh, sorry, my mistake,)))) for some reason I keep 2:50 in my head and not 2:05)))